# How do I find the height of an isosceles triangle given only the vertex angle and the two legs?

Tags: trigonometry

The vertex angle (#) is 140 degrees, the two equal legs (r) are 14 centimeters, the base length (b) and the height/altitude (y) are unknown. My textbook simply states that y = rsin#, but I do not understand how they came to this conclusion.

Comment: `y = r sin #` That doesn't give you the altitude.

Comment: The best hint I can give is to bisect the apex (the 140 degree angle) and create two right triangles. Write the ratios and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$\dfrac b{\sin140^\circ}=\dfrac{14}{\sin20^\circ}$$

$$\dfrac y{14}=\sin20^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

If you recall the definition, for a right triangle, of $\sin (\theta) =$ opposite side of triangle / hypotenuse for right triangles. Next you must find out how to turn the isosceles triangle into multiple right triangles to use this definition. Then with some algebra you can find out if your result is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be $y=r\cos\frac\theta2$, which you can see by dividing the vertex angle in half, giving you a right triangle.